# What is the use of gethost() method in apex

Tags: apex

Can anyone tell me what is the use of gethost() method in apex .And why we use it.

Comment: You can check out the info here : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getHost

Comment: What don't you understand about it ? Please understand that we expect some effort of yourself (looking in the documentation , explaning your question to us .. ) when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The URL instance method `getHost()` is used to get the hostname of the Salesforce server that you are using. For instance, if your Salesforce instance is ap1 then you would get the result as "`ap1.salesforce.com`".

In case of custom domains, suppose your org has a custom domain "`my-dev-org`" the method would return "`my-dev-org.ap1.my.salesforce.com`"

You can try out the function in anonymous execution block:

```
system.debug(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost());
```

Reference: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getHost